# npm install server side, bower install client side for application using a component

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

so, I have developed a small angular component (called myComponent) , that uses angular on the client side, and some server-side portions to persist data to the database.

Now, I want to use that component in another project (myApp).

***npm install myComponent*** inside myApp works, installing the component into **myapp/node_modules/myComponent**

what I want to do automatically is then install the client portion into ***myApp/bower_components/myComponent***

what is the best way to do this ? I tried adding a postinstall script to the package.json of the component, but seems to run bower install in the node_modules/myComponent directory, which was not what I wanted to do

How have other people approached this ? I would rather not split the project into a myComponent-server and myComponent-client, so is there any other approach that works for you ?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are writing universal javascript (isomorphic) I would recommend splitting the module into a server and a client module.
This way your server side code is not dependant on an angular front end and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks Andreas - to be fair they are already in a separate folder for each (app/client and app/server) - I just didn't want the user to have to say

npm install my-component-server
and
bower install my-component-client

but if that's the way of the world, who am I to buck it ? ;)